# cd to directory starting with '-' dash

Tags: bash

I'm learning Git and my very first task is to navigate to a directory where my project will live. Unfortunately, my primary folder for my documents has the following form `- folder1 -` for sorting purposes, and each time I enter;

```
cd - folder1 -
```

I receive the error;

> bash: cd: too many arguments

After searching for a solution I have tried;

```
cd -- folder1 -
cd ./- folder1 -
cd .- folder1 -
cd /- folder1 -
```

and even changing the directory to the parent directory and trying a longer path but this doesn't work either

```
cd ..
cd parent/- folder1 -
```

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with `git`.

Comment: If you have embedded whitespace in the directory name then you need to quote it `cd '- folder1 -'`.  Doesn't really matter if you use single or double quotes here.  I can't stop myself say that you made a poor choice of directory names, whitespace in name always causes more work.

Comment: If you explain why you need the spaces in the filename to do a proper sorting we can propose a better way of naming them. Using spaces in filenames means extra work if you need to write them on the command line, and I would not want to start a filename with a `-` either because of ugly things like: "let's remove my file that is called `-rf .`"

Comment: I apologies for the incorrect label. What should it have been?

Comment: I have only used GUIs to this point. "-" as a starting character for Windows to list it first in the directory and the rest is simply aesthetic. Thank you for your comments. I will take them on board for future projects.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if your filenames have spaces or special chars like `$` put them in single or double quotes. As another rule of thumb, if one of your arguments starts with a `-` and your command is interpreting it as an option instead of a filename (an option like the `-n` in in `echo -n myfile`) then you need to put a `--` as an argument to your command.

So to solve your problem try this:

```
cd "- folder1 -"
```

If `cd` continues to think your folder name is an option, then do this:

```
cd -- "- folder1 -"
```

Comment: +1 `cd -- "- folder1 -"` for me. The other one `cd "- folder1 -"` didn't work though. I was using gitbash

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do directly with Git itself, but with your shell.

The `too many arguments` error is due to the dashes(or tacks, depending on how you call'em) being interpreted as either arguments being passed to the cd command or invalid flags/switches/options, etc.

In order to fix this, you'll have to prevent the dashes from being interpreted as flags.

In this case, you'll enter `cd -- -\ folder1\ -/` OR `cd -- "- folder1 -"`

the `--` after `cd` basically says "no flags please" and then the backslashes are escaping the spaces after the dashes in the folder name.

I highly suggest using a different naming convention as this can get VERY cumbersome and time consuming.

Comment: I feel your answer not only has provided the solution but has also helped me understand the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I can't provide credit to both you and MondKin and they were first. Your answer is still greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 0):

try using double-quotes:

```
cd "- folder1 -"
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my end. Neither single or double quotes work. Instead I get; "bash: cd: - : invalid option \\ cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]"

Comment: are you in the directory containing -folder-? if you list the contents (use 'ls' to list the contents of the directory) can you see -folder-? If so, type 'cd -' and then hit the tab key; the rest of the line should auto-complete.

Comment: It doesn't work this way since `cd` tries to interpret the directory name as a flag regardless of quotation marks. The only solution is to put two dashes before passing the directory name.